# Как в ASP.Net Core работать с PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core

С помощью каких библиотек Вы работаете в ASP.Net Core с PostgreSQL?

Comment: Если для EF - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

Comment: Для начала используй EntityFramework и паттерн "Репозиторий". Когда EntityFramework будет не справляться с нагрузкой, просто заменишь на что нибудь другое и все.

Answer (score 4):

Можете использовать

- [Entity Framework](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/).
- Чистый ADO.NET.
- Dapper (методы расширения для ADO.NET).
  [Рабочий пример](http://techbrij.com/asp-net-core-postgresql-dapper-crud).